# heroku is given a 403 forbidden for a New::HTTP.new ... any idea why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

```
  uri = URI.parse("https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2010-08-01/distribution/#{config['cloud_dist_id']}/invalidation")
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
  req.initialize_http_header({
    'x-amz-date' => date,
    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
    'Authorization' => "AWS %s:%s" % [config['access_key_id'], Base64.encode64(digest.digest)]
  })
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  res = http.request(req)
```

When I output:

```
  puts http.inspect
  puts res.inspect
```

Locally it works fine:

```
#<Net::HTTP cloudfront.amazonaws.com:443 open=false>
#<Net::HTTPCreated 201 Created readbody=true>
```

But on heroku:

```
#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>
Failed 403
```

Any idea why this is failing on heroku. Why it's forbidden? Thanks

Comment: Just a tip: If you can't find help anywhere, you can always give Heroku support a try. https://support.heroku.com/requests/new

Answer (score 1):

Heroku adds additional output headers your application is not aware of at the moment of signing your request.

Try to explicitly limit scope of headers which participate in signature, there are some options in AWS API for this

Answer (score 0):

make it test with heroku console.

It should work as i am using same thing but using HTTParty.

Thanks